# Wrapping R code chunks in KnitR to fit width in html when posting to Wordpress

Tags: r, wordpress, knitr

I'm trying to use the `knit2wp()` function of `knitr` in order to blog to Wordpress as discussed here: http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/wordpress/

My problem is that, despite trying various options to control chunk width, including setting tidy.opts in the chunk options, and adjusting global width settings as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12176296/knitr-how-to-prevent-text-wrapping-in-output), my R code chunks won't wrap around, resulting in overly wide code chunks that require scrolling sideways to view them, like [this](http://yihui.wordpress.com/2013/12/14/test-one/).

Is there a setting that I'm missing that will cause R code chunks to wrap around? Also, is there a setting that will widen the grey boxes that appear in Wordpress for the code chunks? None of the width options seem to have any effect.

This is what my setup chunk currently looks like:

`````
```{r setup, echo=FALSE}
library(knitr)
opts_knit$set(upload.fun = function(file) imgur_upload(file, key = "xxxx"))
opts_chunk$set(fig.width=5, fig.height=5, fig.align = 'center', cache=TRUE, tidy = FALSE)
````
`````

I have also tried adding the line `options(width = 80)` to that chunk, as well as setting `tidy.opts` within each chunk, and none of these has had any effect.

Comment: did you try adding `tidy = FALSE` to the global chunk options?

Comment: I have tried that, though I'll double-check it

Comment: Have double checked - opts_chunk(tidy = false) does not do the trick

Comment: I have worked on this some more - tidy = FALSE stops knitr from removing manually inserted new lines, so it is helpful if you want to manually format all of your code to fit within a certain width (which would perhaps be easy enough with the formatR package). However, this still doesn't work for table output, and an automatic solution would be preferable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a dirty fix, you may add `word-wrap: break-word;` in css file to your `pre` element. Or embed it to a html file.

EDIT1:

Final advise is on the bottom. I am not an expert in WP, so you will have to work out the solution yourself.

As for how it will look, you may try it in a browser. There is an example with this page. You choose the element and may see a style on left. You may fix it in your browser (Right click, then "Inspect element" in Chrome) to see how it will look. However, this is not a permanent change: you change your local version. Refresh the page to get back to original.

[image]

Now I turn word wrapping off (better change it to `break-word`):

[image]

If you satisfied with result of in-browser if, there are to options to make change it in server:

1. If we play dirty anyway, you may embed the style tag into your template somewhere. Wrap it in a style tag (Editor removes them, so i am not able to post it):

   pre {word-wrap: break-word}
2. Edit you css and either create a new class or fix the ones that you have.  I ma not sure how to do it with wordpress, but there is some information here: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-edit-css-style-sheet

I believe that the right approach is the second, but if you want result ASAP, you may try the first one as it looks easier.

Comment: I'm not really very experienced with css, so could you elaborate? Would I add this code somewhere in a single css sheet for my Wordpress blog, or on each individual post page?

Comment: I think, you should add it to a single page. A template (if you paste the style in html) or change the css file.

Comment: Ok, so I have added that line to the end of the pre element in the theme css (accessed through 'appearance' -> 'editor'). However, this does not appear to change the output.

Comment: Could you give me a link to your blog? I will have a look.

Comment: I tinkered around a little and now word-wrap: break-word; in the pre section of the css seems to be working as intended (not sure why I couldn't get it happening before, perhaps a typo). I appreciate the time and thought-out answer. At the end of the day, it seems like manually breaking my code and comments and allowing wide tables to scroll might end up looking more attractive, but I'm glad to have this level of control, and my question is answered. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you too. I saw this guys breaking the code manually http://www.carlboettiger.info/2012/02/28/knitr-with-flickr-and-wordpress.html.
They also have word-wrap: break-word; but it looks ugly when it happens.