# In R markdown in RStudio, how can I prevent the source code from running off a pdf page?

Tags: r, rstudio

I currently have some code that looks like so:

````
```{r, tidy=TRUE}
plot(DT$age, DT$height, xlab = "Age of participant in Trials", ylab = "Height of participant in       Trials")
```
````

Now, it was my understanding that setting `tidy` to `TRUE` would make it so that when I knit the code together, the code would not go running off the page and would wrap by itself. However, I sporadically still get run off source code displays when I do commands like the one above. Is there another function that would guarantee the wrapping of code? Thanks!

Comment: Not a great solution, but try [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41471/getting-sweave-code-chunks-to-stay-inside-page-margins).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [knitr: How to prevent text wrapping in output?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12176296/knitr-how-to-prevent-text-wrapping-in-output)

Answer (score 46):

Use the `width.cutoff` argument inside `tidy.opts` knitr options to specify the output width :

````
```{r, tidy=TRUE, tidy.opts=list(width.cutoff=60)}
plot(DT$age, DT$height, xlab = "Age of participant in Trials", ylab = "Height of participant in trials")
```
````

You can define this option globally for your whole file with a chunk like this :

````
```{r}
library(knitr)
opts_chunk$set(tidy.opts=list(width.cutoff=60),tidy=TRUE)
```
````

The `tidy.opts` options are passed to the `formatR` package which does the tidying (if I understand correctly). In-depth informations about `formatR` can be found here :

http://yihui.name/formatR/

Comment: This doesn't work with long urls (let's say an string with no spaces) when exporting to PDF, they are just out of margin.

Comment: This is not working for me either. Could it be because the code in my chunks are bash, not R? ie. it looks like `{bash, eval=F}` and the commands run off the pdf page

Comment: This doesn't work for me in R, not standalone in each line, not with global options. Trying this right now and it's not working: ```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, tidy.opts=list(width.cutoff=60), tidy=TRUE)
``` I have a very long line defining a matrix and it's not wrapped, despite has plenty of spaces inside.

Answer (score 11):

The `formatR` solution also did not work for me, what worked for me was adding the below code to the [YAML metadata](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/html-document.html)

```
---
title: ...
author: ...
header-includes:
  \usepackage{fvextra}
  \DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Highlighting}{Verbatim}{breaklines,commandchars=\\\{\}}
---
```

In the .tex file, the `Highlighting` environment is used to print the code. The code above redefines the default `Highlighting` environment to include the `breaklines` option, which requires the `fvextra` package and creates the line wrap for us.

Comment: I just want to add for anyone reading this in the future that this suggestion worked for me, whereas the advice at the link https://intro2r.com/tips-tricks.html did not work for me. Now my R code wraps properly and does not run off the page. Thanks.

Comment: Would also just note that it actually needs to be "- \usepackage{fvextra}" and "- \Defineblahblah" in front of each line to make it work in the .Rmd file.

Comment: This works successfully, very helpful.