# R Markdown Knitr to PDF Code Outside Margin

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

I want to attach the entirety of my code chunks at the end of my document. The code includes plots, inserted graphics, calculations and so forth. It's long. This is after I have run the relevant code in its respective chapters. At this point, I don't want the code to generate any results, but simply show the code so that others can check on what I have done.

Here is an example of part of the code:

```
shapefile1 <- readOGR("./Folder1/Folder2/Folder3", layer = "TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3") # Read in world shapefile
```

When I compile, it shows up outside the margin that I have set for my document in the YAML header like this

```
geometry: top=2.5cm, bottom=2cm, left=3cm, right=3.5cm
```

I have tried the following solutions:

Option 1:

[In R markdown in RStudio, how can I prevent the source code from running off a pdf page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26210656/in-r-markdown-in-rstudio-how-can-i-prevent-the-source-code-from-running-off-a-p)

````
```{r, eval=FALSE, tidy=TRUE, tidy.opts=list(width.cutoff=60)}
```
````

Option 2:

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133810/knitr-plotting-outside-margin

````
```{r, eval=FALSE, out.width=".9\\paperwidth"}
```
````

Neither works for me. The only other thing I can think of is manually making the code lines shorter, but I'm sure that can't be the best option. How is this done?

Answer (score 1):

This happens to me when I use "pdflatex" as the Latex Engine in R Studio. When I change to "xelatex", this doesn't happen anymore. But I also need this code chunk in the beggining of the markdown:

```
library(knitr)
# Set so that long lines in R will be wrapped:
opts_chunk$set(tidy.opts=list(width.cutoff=40),tidy=TRUE)
```