# R Bookdown: code wrapping does not work for HTML gitbook output

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown

I have code-blocks that I want wrapped in a R bookdown format. I am rendering to gitbook. All the code-blocks currently don't wrap, instead they give a horizontal scroll bar.

When I take the same code-block, and render it in a regular RMarkdown file to html, code-wrapping works instantly.

I know that when you want to force a certain character-width, you can so using the answers provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26212045/3578190). But this doesn't work either.

Is this a limitation of the gitbook format? Is there any way to work around it?