# Wrap horizontal code overflow in Quarto revealjs

Tags: r, overflow, quarto, reveal.js

Is there a way to have long lines of code wrapped in Quarto, revealjs output? `code-overflow: wrap`, which works for `html` output does not seem to work in `revealjs`:

````
---
format: revealjs
---

## A title

```{r}
#| echo: true
#| code-overflow: wrap
multipoint <- sf::st_multipoint(rbind(c(3.2,4), c(3,4.6), c(3.8,4.4), c(3.5,3.8), c(3.4,3.6), c(3.9,4.5)))
#This should be wrapped.
```
````

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`width.cutoff`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26210656/in-r-markdown-in-rstudio-how-can-i-prevent-the-source-code-from-running-off-a-p) property (only a viable option if you render via `knitr`):

````
---
format: revealjs
---

## A title


Here is some example code

```{r}
#| eval: false
#| echo: true
#| tidy: true
#| tidy.opts: { width.cutoff: 60 }
multipoint <- sf::st_multipoint(rbind(c(3.2,4), c(3,4.6), c(3.8,4.4), c(3.5,3.8), c(3.4,3.6), c(3.9,4.5)))
```
````

[image]

Comment: This works, thanks! Note that adding `width.cutoff` as an option with the hash pipe `#|` does not seem to be supported yet, weirdly enough...

Comment: Yes, I do not find a way either..if you want to follow up on this, I created a question in [quarto discussion](https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/discussions/5813).

Comment: Just one thing, this probably would not work with `jupyter` engine or any engine other than `knitr`.

Comment: `#| tidy.opts: { width.cutoff: 60 }` works @Maël

Comment: Note that "... from next knitr version 1.44 (and from current dev version 1.43.7), all dash options are changed to their dot versions. This includes tidy-opts which means it can be used in YAML and correctly replace knitr's defaults" [Link](https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/discussions/5813)