# R Markdown pdf document: outputs is to wide and extends beyond the page

Tags: r, r-markdown, texreg

I am creating a markdown document to provide the supervisors of my thesis with my R script. Everything is working fine, except for one detail:

I include the outputs of a regression by using `'texreg'`:

````
### 2.4 Output
```{r output}
texreg(list(M1aR,M1bR,M1cR,M1dR), dcolumn = TRUE, booktabs = TRUE, 
       stars = c(0.01, 0.05, 0.1),
       include.adjrs = FALSE, caption = "Lifetime CO2", digits = 4, 
       reorder.coef = c(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,1))
```
````

In the PDF file, the generated Latex code exceeds the page width and the last few words can not be seen.
I tried using different options such as

```
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: pdflatex
    geometry: "left=2cm, right=2cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm"
```

in the header.
I also tried options in the chunk:

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(out.width="80%")  
texreg(list(M1aR,M1bR,M1cR,M1dR), dcolumn = TRUE, booktabs = TRUE, 
       stars = c(0.01, 0.05, 0.1),
       include.adjrs = FALSE, caption = "Lifetime CO2", digits = 4, 
       reorder.coef = c(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,1))
```

But nothing worked.  The `formatR` package is installed and called. Any suggestions anyone? Would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Does this question resolve the issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33481271/how-to-wrap-code-and-the-output-in-markdown-rmd. Without a reproducible example [MRE] not possible to comment further; suspect this is a duplicate and vote to close.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to wrap code and the output in markdown (.Rmd)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33481271/how-to-wrap-code-and-the-output-in-markdown-rmd)

Comment: it seems to be the same problem, but I've got the package called and it is still not working...

Comment: Without a minimal reproducible question it will be difficult to help you. Here is a link help with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example. It may also be worth looking at other rmarkdown pdf type questions on StackOverflow to see how its done. Basically you need to ensure that in a fresh version of R the question can be copied from SO and the code run to reproduce the problem. I may take a bit to time to get the hang of this, but hopefully this helps.