# .Rmd output after created in a tabItem creates a second dashboard in the body of all tabItems of the shiny dashboard

Tags: r, shiny, markdown, shinydashboard

I have a shinydashboard with 3 tabItems. In the 3rd which is named `Results` a rmd file is displayed. The issue is that as soon as I open this tab and display the rmd report the body in the other tabs is spoiled and its like a second dashboard is included inside the main body. Any idea why this happens?

The ex.rmd file

```
---
title: "An example Knitr/R Markdown document"
output: html_document
---


{r chunk_name, include=FALSE}
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- 2*x + rnorm(100)
cor(x, y)
```

and the app.r file

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(shinyjs)
library(knitr)
dbHeader <- dashboardHeaderPlus(

)

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPagePlus(
    header = dbHeader,
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(
                               sidebarMenu(id = "sidebar", # id important for updateTabItems
                                           menuItem("Welcome", tabName = "well", icon = icon("house")),
                                           menuItem("Consent", tabName = "conse", icon = icon("line-chart")),
                                           menuItem("Results", tabName = "res", icon = icon("line-chart"))
                               )           ),
    body = dashboardBody(
      
      useShinyjs(),
      tags$script(HTML("$('body').addClass('fixed');")),
      
      tags$head(tags$style(".skin-blue .main-header .logo { padding: 0px;}")),
      tabItems(
        tabItem("well",
                fluidRow(
                  column(5,),
                  column(6,
                         actionButton("button", "Get started",style='padding:4px; font-size:140%')))),
        tabItem("conse",
                fluidRow(column(3,h3("Concent"))),
                fluidRow(column(3,h5(strong("Purpose of the research")))),
                fluidRow(column(12,"Your practice is being invited to participate in a study which aims to explore the relationship of statin prescriptions and all cause mortality in elderly general practice patients")),
                
                
        ),
        tabItem("res",
                tags$hr(),
                fluidRow(
                  column(3,actionButton('spdf', "Save PDF",style='padding:4px; font-size:180%')
                  ),
                  column(6,
                         uiOutput('markdown'))))
      ),
      
      
      
    )
    
  ),
  server<-shinyServer(function(input, output,session) { 
    output$markdown <- renderUI({
      HTML(markdown::markdownToHTML(knit('ex.rmd', quiet = TRUE)))
    })

  }
  )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rmd code adds the property

`max-width: 800px;`

To remove it you can use fragment.only option

```
HTML(markdown::markdownToHTML(knit('exx.rmd', quiet = TRUE), fragment.only=TRUE))
```

Alternatively, you can add the following to your `ui`.

```
tags$head(tags$style(HTML("
                               body {
                                  width: 100% !important;
                                  max-width: 100% !important;
                               }

                               ")))
```

Then there is no impact on the previous tabs.

Comment: Thanks for your proposals but how vould I maintain this A4 paper width in the third tab (rmd) only and also maintain the 100% width in the other 2 tabs?

Comment: `fragment.only=TRUE` option does not work?

Comment: it is working but I was wondering if somehow i could keep those A4 limits in this certain tab that are created without using fragment=T

Comment: I have not tried it.  Perhaps you can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36845178/width-of-r-code-chunk-output-in-rmarkdown-files-knitr-ed-to-html/36846864#36846864)