# Widening output from code in rmarkdown html

Tags: css, r, r-markdown, knitr

I am trying to display some regression results in an rmarkdown html file. However, the output from the code chunks is too narrow and therefore it is very hard to read the p-values, etc, particularly when I include a floating table of contents. I have tried adjusting `options(width = 9999)` but this does not seem to fix the issue. I have also tried:

```
<style>
pre {
  overflow-x: auto;
}
pre code {
  word-wrap: normal;
  white-space: pre;
}
</style>
```

which allows me to scroll horizontally if needed. However, given I am using regression results, I do not like having to scroll back and forth to read the coefficients and p-values. I have also tried:

```
<style>
.main-container { width: 1200px; max-width:2800px;}
</style>
```

adjusting the `width` and `max-width` values, to no avail. These solutions are suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36845178/width-of-r-code-chunk-output-in-rmarkdown-files-knitr-ed-to-html/36846864).

Any idea how I can solve this issue?

Here is an example. Unfortunately I cannot post my regression results, so here is a matrix that essentially replicates the same issue:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "me"
date: "11/10/2021"
output: 
    html_document:
      toc: true
      tow_float: true
     
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
options(width = 9999)
````

```
matrix = matrix(rnorm(100,5,2), ncol = 20)
matrix
```

However, when I knit the document, I get something like this:

[image]

How can I make the output wider?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Width of R code chunk output in RMarkdown files knitr-ed to html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36845178/width-of-r-code-chunk-output-in-rmarkdown-files-knitr-ed-to-html)

Comment: @manro This is the post I referenced in my post. I tried the things suggested here, and they seem to work when I do not have a table of contents. However, when I include the TOC they don't seem to work

Comment: hmm... I will see

Answer (score 1):

I found out, where is your problem.

The **floating toc** is guilty.

Look, I took a code from that post and remove `toc_float`.

````
---
title: "R Notebook"
author: "me"
date: "11/10/2021"
output:
  html_document:
    toc: true    
---


<style>
.main-container { width: 1800px; max-width:2800px;}
</style>

## R Markdown

```{r}
options(width = 1500)
dataM <- matrix(rnorm(100, 5, 2), ncol = 20)
dataM
```
````

And it **works:**

[image]

I think, that this **space** under toc **is reserved**. But can't say it with 100% confidence.

---

**An addition**

You should make a custom TOC with CSS.
I'm not a pro with CSS, so, I have compiled something for you. You can modify it...

**CSS-file:**

```
#TOC { 
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
    color:black; 
    background-color: white;     
    position: fixed; 
    top: 0; 
    left: 0; 
    width: 150px; 
    border: 1px solid Black;
    padding: 10px; 
    margin: 30px;
    overflow:auto;      
 }

body {
  max-width: 800px;  
  margin-left:210px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
```

**Your header:**

```
---
title: "R Notebook"
author: "me"
date: "11/10/2021"
output:
  html_document:
    css: TOC.css
    toc: true
---
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. That does work, but my actual markdown document is quite long, so I would like to keep the floating toc. Do you know of another solution that will allow me to keep the toc?

Comment: @z_11122 Yes, we can. I will add info to my answer.

Comment: @z_11122 If i helped to you, you can accept my answer ;)

Comment: It looks like this answer helped.  Pinging here to have the answer flagged as accepted.